# Prevenir que FormData realice un submit

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, formdata

¡Hola!

Estoy intentando hacer una llamada a una API hecha en Flask que recibe una imagen para luego procesarla.

Estoy intentando hacerlo a través de AJAX utilizando un `FormData`, pero éste realiza un `submit` incluso aunque haya usado `ev.preventDefault()`.

Este es el código:

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $("#form-add").on("submit", function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:4455/upload-image',
            data: new FormData(this),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(respuesta){
                if(respuesta.error == 0){
                    console.log(respuesta);
                    $("#imgProcesada").attr("src", respuesta.dir)
                    $("#imgContainer").removeClass("d-none");

                } else {
                    console.log("Error1");
                    console.log(respuesta);
                }
             },
             error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 console.log("Error AJAX");
             }
        });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
    <form id="form-add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="javascript:void(0)">
        <input type="file" name="file1">
        <button type="submit" value="submit">Enviar</button>
    </form>
```

¿Cómo puedo evitar que se realice el `submit`?

Pude comprobar que si elimino la línea `data: new FormData(this),` esto ya no ocurre.

¡Gracias!

Comment: Probando el código aquí el formulario no hace submit. Puede que tengas más código que esté provocando este comportamiento.